# please help with matrix operation

Tags: matrices

I want to look for the unknown matrix C in the equation:

$$
[C']*[B] + [C']*[A]*[C] -k=0,
$$

where C' is the transpose matrix of C with the dimension 1x4 and C is 4X1, C is the unknown to be determined and B is a 4X1 column matrix, A is 4x4 square matrix while k is a scale. Please I need to find the unknown matrix C.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $C$ is an $4\times 1$ matrix and $A$ is $2\times 2$, the product $C^T A C$ hardly makes any sense.

Comment: A is 4x4 and not 2x2 it is a mistake.

Comment: In general, the solution is not unique. What exactly do you mean by "find the unknown matrix"? Do you know in advance that there is exactly one correct solution? If you are looking for multiple (infinitely many) solutions, then in what form are you looking for these solutions?

Comment: Are we given any information about the matrix $A$? For instance, is it known that $A$ is symmetric? Is it known that $A$ is positive definite?

Comment: Matrix A is symmetric and positive definite. The unknown is matrix C.